# Why exactly should I not call free() on variables not allocated by malloc()?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, free, malloc

I read somewhere that it is disastrous to use `free` to get rid of an object not created by calling `malloc`, is this true? why?

Comment: Just a minor semantic correction: There are no "objects" in C. Better would be "variable", or "structure".

Comment: @Chris The K&R book, it states (somewhere by the end) that object is any memory location that can be referenced by a name (or so I recall, I cant find my copy)

Comment: @Chris Cooper: Just because some people say that C isn't "object oriented" doesn't mean that there's no such thing as an object in that language.  From the C spec: "object: region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values."  There you have it.

Comment: i am not talking of object here as it is in the OOP paradigm...

Comment: A nice defending-programming technique is to make your pointer NULL after the free(pointer). In this way, you can check if it has been freed already.

Comment: Its not _disasterous_, its _undefined_, there is a big difference. You are free to make _any_ undefined behavior consistent and possibly even useful provided that you make the modifications yourself, without breaking any _defined_ behavior.

Comment: @Tom @Dietrich @ultrajohn: Haha ok thanks everyone. I hadn't heard that terminology outside of OOP before. Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's undefined behavior - never try it.

Let's see what happens when you try to `free()` an automatic variable. The heap manager will have to deduce how to take ownership of the memory block. To do so it will either have to use some separate structure that lists all allocated blocks and that is very slow an rarely used or hope that the necessary data is located near the beginning of the block.

The latter is used quite often and here's how i is supposed to work. When you call malloc() the heap manager allocates a slightly bigger block, stores service data at the beginning and returns an offset pointer. Smth like:

```
void* malloc( size_t size )
{
      void* block = tryAlloc( size + sizeof( size_t) );
      if( block == 0 ) {
          return 0;
      }
      // the following is for illustration, more service data is usually written
      *((size_t*)block) = size;
      return (size_t*)block + 1;
 }
```

then `free()` will try to access that data by offsetting the passed pointer but if the pointer is to an automatic variable whatever data will be located where it expects to find service data. Hence undefined behavior. Many times service data is modified by `free()` for heap manager to take ownership of the block - so if the pointer passed is to an automatic variable some unrelated memory will be modified and read from.

Implementations may vary but you should never make any specific assumptions. Only call `free()` on addresses returned by `malloc()` family functions.

Comment: You'd have to `tryAlloc(size + sizeof(size_t))` to have room for the `size_t` in front.

Comment: Usually there is a scheme followed to allocate memory (and more is allocated to store size, prevent seg-fault to *some* extent, etc). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650895/if-free-knows-the-length-of-my-array-why-cant-i-ask-for-it-in-my-own-code/2652417#2652417

Comment: Fix #2: You cast `block` to the right type, but forget to dereference it afterwards.

Comment: I think you meant "never try it _unless_ your implementation defines the behavior" ... e.g. writing your own logging / garbage collecting malloc() subsystem. You are free to define any undefined behavior, that's why its undefined. (as long as you don't _break_ defined behavior).

Comment: @Tim Post: Then the code will expose undefined behavior on any other implementation. What will you do then?

Comment: @sharptooth - I didn't mean it was a good idea, I was simply pointing out undefined can be implementation defined. For instance, an embedded router .. a kid's toy .. a mobile device .. or anywhere else that you might fiddle with malloc() for whatever reason.

Comment: @sharptooth - also, implementation defined doesn't always mean _host_ implementation defined. For instance, if using uclibc and shipping it as part of the build.

Answer (score 13):

By the standard, it's "undefined behavior" - i.e. "anything can happen". That's usually bad things, though.

In practice: `free`'ing a pointer means modifying the heap.  C runtime does virtually never validate if the pointer passed comes from the heap - that would be to costly in either time or memory. Combine these two factoids, and you get "free(non-malloced-ptr) will write something somewhere" - the resutl may be some of "your" data modified behind your back, an access violation, or trashing vital runtime structures, such as a return address on the stack.

***Example: A disastrous scenario:***
Your heap is implemented as a simple list of free blocks. malloc means removing a suitable block from the list, free means adding it to the list again.  (a typical if trivial implementation)

You free() a pointer to a local variable on the stack. You are "lucky" because the modification goes into irrelevant stack space. However, part of the stack is now on your free list.

Because of the allocator design and your allocation patterns, malloc is unlikely to return this block. Later, in an completely unrelated part of the program, you actually do get this block as malloc result, writing to it trashes some local variables up the stack, and when returning some vital pointer contains garbage and your app crashes. Symptoms, repro and location are completely unrelated to the actual cause.

Debug that.

Answer (score 6):

[It is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Freeing_unallocated_memory) undefined behaviour. And logically, if behaviour is undefined, you cannot be sure what has happened, and if the program is still operating properly.

Comment: but, how and why does it lead to an undefined behavior?

Comment: Why? Because the standard says it does. How? I don't know. If we knew how it happened, it wouldn't be undefined.

Comment: @Chris: Why does "undefined behavior" always involve nasal demons, but not something nice, say, world peace?

Comment: @peterchen - Because if undefined behavior involved world peace, I'd be all for it.

Comment: @peterchen: The Standard never says that UB can't be world peace. It can be world peace or whatever else.

Comment: @ultrajohn Because the C language standard doesn't define it, and there many, many C compilers out there (`gcc` and `clang` being only two examples), every compiler writer can choose to implement what happens differently. That's why it leads to undefined behavior; the behavior _is_ defined for each compiler, but doesn't necessarily need to be defined the same way for every other compiler.

Answer (score 6):

Some people have pointed out here that this is "undefined behavior".  I'm going to go farther and say that on some implementations, this will either crash your program or cause data corruption.  It has to do with how "malloc" and "free" are implemented.

One possible way to implement malloc/free is to put a small header before each allocated region.  On a malloc'd region, that header would contain the size of the region.  When the region is freed, that header is checked and the region is added to the appropriate freelist.  If this happens to you, this is bad news.  For example, if you free an object allocated on the stack, suddenly part of the stack is in the freelist.  Then malloc might return that region in response to a future call, and you'll scribble data all over your stack.  Another possibility is that you free a string constant.  If that string constant is in read-only memory (it often is), this hypothetical implementation would cause a segfault and crash either after a later malloc or when free adds the object to its freelist.

This is a hypothetical implementation I am talking about, but you can use your imagination to see how it could go very, very wrong.  Some implementations are very robust and are not vulnerable to this precise type of user error.  Some implementations even allow you to set environment variables to diagnose these types of errors.  Valgrind and other tools will also detect these errors.

Comment: undefined behavior as officially defined - `behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements`. Since standard imposes no requirements, there are bound to be different implementations and the program _may_ crash on some implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, this is not true. calloc() and realloc() are valid object sources for free(), too. ;)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are correct. However, calloc() and realloc() are just convenient interfaces to malloc(). If given a platform with only malloc() and memcpy(), one could quickly implement calloc() and realloc() in just a few minutes.

Comment: Not exactly. To copy the data for realloc, you need to know the size of the old memory block.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at what [undefined behavior means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `malloc()` and `free()` on a conforming *hosted* C implementation are built to standards. The standards say the behavior of calling `free()` on a heap block that was not returned by `malloc()` (or something wrapping it, e.g. `calloc()`) is undefined.

This means, it can do whatever you *want* it to do, provided that you make the necessary modifications to `free()` on your own. You won't *break* the standard by making the behavior of `free()` on blocks not allocated by `malloc()` *consistent* and even possibly *useful*.

In fact, there could be platforms that (themselves) *define* this behavior. I don't know of any, but there could be some. There are several garbage collecting / logging malloc() implementations that might let it fail more gracefully while logging the event. But thats *implementation* , not *standards* defined behavior.

*Undefined* simply means don't count on any kind of consistent behavior unless you implement it yourself *without breaking any defined behavior*. Finally, *implementation defined* does not always mean defined by the host system. Many programs link against (and ship) [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/). In that case, the implementation is self contained, consistent *and* portable.

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly be *possible* for an implementation of `malloc`/`free` to keep a list of the memory blocks thats been allocated and in the case the user tries to free a block that isn't in this list do nothing.

However since the standard says that this isn't a requirement most implementation will treat all pointers coming into free as valid.