# Maximum memory which malloc can allocate

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, malloc, cpu-architecture

I was trying to figure out how much memory I can malloc to maximum extent on my machine
(1 Gb RAM 160 Gb HD Windows platform).

I read that the maximum memory malloc can allocate is limited to physical memory (on heap).

Also when a program exceeds consumption of memory to a certain level, the computer stops working because other applications do not get enough memory that they require.

So to confirm, I wrote a small program in C:

```
int main(){  
    int *p;
    while(1){
        p=(int *)malloc(4);
        if(!p)break;
    }   
}
```

I was hoping that there would be a time when memory allocation would fail and the loop would break, but my computer hung as it was an infinite loop.

I waited for about an hour and finally I had to force shut down my computer.

Some questions:

- Does malloc allocate memory from HD also?
- What was the reason for above behaviour?
- Why didn't loop break at any point of time?
- Why wasn't there any allocation failure?

Comment: Anyway, why malloc(4), and why not malloc(4096), or malloc(8192), or else ?

Comment: ofcourse it can be anything which is multiple of sizeof int.
Isn't it?

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: No, there's a very significant difference between large mallocs like `malloc(1ULL<<30)` vs. many tiny mallocs.  You'll run out of virtual address space the first way before you run out RAM+swap to store the bookkeeping info, instead of swap thrashing as you use up all the physical RAM.  When your allocations are many pages, most of the pages are untouched even if malloc stores bookkeeping info at the start of each allocation.  And tiny allocations use more space for bookkeeping and alignment than for the actual 4-byte allocation, so if you were counting total alloced size, huge overhead.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> I read that the maximum memory `malloc` can allocate is limited to physical memory (on heap).

Wrong: most computers/OSs support *virtual* memory, backed by disk space.

> Some questions: does `malloc` allocate memory from HDD also?

`malloc` asks the OS, which in turn may well use some disk space.

> What was the reason for above behavior? Why didn't the loop break at any time?
>
> Why wasn't there any allocation failure?

You just asked for too little at a time: the loop would have broken eventually (well after your machine slowed to a crawl due to the large excess of virtual vs physical memory and the consequent super-frequent disk access, an issue known as "thrashing") but it exhausted your patience well before then.  Try getting e.g. a megabyte at a time instead.

> When a program exceeds consumption of memory to a certain level, the
> computer stops working because other applications do not get enough
> memory that they require.

A total stop is unlikely, but when an operation that normally would take a few microseconds ends up taking (e.g.) tens of milliseconds, those four orders of magnitude may certainly make it *feel* as if the computer had basically stopped, and what would normally take a minute could take a week.

Comment: your memory size is 1GB doesnt mean that malloc will go all the way there. It really depends upon the amount of memory your OS assigns to your process. Which by looking at the code in this case will be very low. From there on it goes on to allocate memory on your virtual memory.

Comment: Actually on some platforms malloc might succeed even though the requested size exceeds RAM+swap size. On linux for example asking for memory means to map `/dev/zero` which in turn means just mark up pages as being zero - unless you change the content it doesn't have to consume much memory or swap space.

Comment: But it will fail if the requested size exceeds the address space(on a 32 bit system that's ~4 GB; on most x86_64 systems that's ~16 TB).  If you put something in the memory, it will have to allocate real memory, but it can be compressed if your OS supports compressed memory.

Answer (score 28):

I know this thread is old, but for anyone willing to give it a try oneself, use this code snipped

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int *p;
while(1) {
    int inc=1024*1024*sizeof(char);
    p=(int*) calloc(1,inc);
    if(!p) break;
    }
}
```

run

```
$ gcc memtest.c
$ ./a.out
```

upon running, this code fills up ones RAM until killed by the kernel. Using calloc instead of malloc to prevent "lazy evaluation". Ideas taken from this thread:
[Malloc Memory Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383059/malloc-memory-questions)

This code quickly filled my RAM (4Gb) and then in about 2 minutes my 20Gb swap partition before it died. 64bit Linux of course.

Comment: I just tried the same program on a machine with 192Gb memory/4Gb swap. Within a minute it consumed up to 175Gb, then the swap was slowly filled. When there were only 24kb of swap left, it got killed.

Comment: What you call "lazy evaluation" presumably allows the kernel to use a zero page for each page of allocated but unwritten memory. Compression (especially for swap) and even deduplication (as currently done by some hypervisors) may reduce actual memory required. Of course, malloc has storage overhead, page tables add overhead, the program has non-heap memory, the OS uses memory, etc.

Comment: A good `calloc(3)` implementation doesn't touch the pages after it gets them from `mmap(2)`, because they're already zeroed.  The reason this actually eventually triggers the OOM killer is that malloc's extra bookkeeping info uses memory.  If you `strace` it, you'll see `mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4fc4d14000`.  The allocation size, 1052672, is 1MiB + 4096, and that extra page is presumably what glibc's malloc actually dirties.  e.g. on my desktop with 5GiB of physical memory, I can `calloc` 16GiB (in 1MiB chunks) without disk activity.

Comment: The untouched virtual pages are all still mapped to the same physical zeroed page.

Answer (score 14):

**`/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` controls the maximum on Linux**

On Ubuntu 19.04 for example, [we can easily see that `malloc` is implemented with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS` by using `strace`](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#malloc-implementation).

Then `man proc` then describes how `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` controls the maximum allocation:

> This file contains the kernel virtual memory accounting mode.  Values are:
>
> - 0: heuristic overcommit (this is the default)
> - 1: always overcommit, never check
> - 2: always check, never overcommit
>
> In mode 0, calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not  checked,  and  the  default check is very weak, leading to the risk of getting a process "OOM-killed".
>
> In mode 1, the kernel pretends there is always enough memory, until memory actually runs out.  One use case for this mode is scientific computing applications that em‐ ploy large sparse arrays. In Linux kernel versions before 2.6.0, any nonzero value implies mode 1.
>
> In mode 2 (available since Linux 2.6), the total virtual address space that can  be allocated (CommitLimit in /proc/meminfo) is calculated as
>
> ```
> CommitLimit = (total_RAM - total_huge_TLB) * overcommit_ratio / 100 + total_swap
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - total_RAM is the total amount of RAM on the system;
> - total_huge_TLB is the amount of memory set aside for huge pages;
> - overcommit_ratio is the value in /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio; and
> - total_swap is the amount of swap space.
>
> For  example,  on  a system with 16GB of physical RAM, 16GB of swap, no space dedicated to huge pages, and an overcommit_ratio of 50,  this  formula  yields  a  Com‐ mitLimit of 24GB.
>
> Since  Linux  3.14, if the value in /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_kbytes is nonzero, then CommitLimit is instead calculated as:
>
> ```
> CommitLimit = overcommit_kbytes + total_swap
> ```
>
> See also the description of /proc/sys/vm/admiin_reserve_kbytes and /proc/sys/vm/user_reserve_kbytes.

[Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting.rst](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.2/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting.rst) in the 5.2.1 kernel tree also gives some information, although lol a bit less:

> The Linux kernel supports the following overcommit handling modes
>
> - `0` Heuristic overcommit handling. Obvious overcommits of address
>     space are refused. Used for a typical system. It ensures a
>     seriously wild allocation fails while allowing overcommit to
>     reduce swap usage.  root is allowed to allocate slightly more
>     memory in this mode. This is the default.
> - `1` Always overcommit. Appropriate for some scientific
>     applications. Classic example is code using sparse arrays and
>     just relying on the virtual memory consisting almost entirely
>     of zero pages.
> - `2` Don't overcommit. The total address space commit for the
>     system is not permitted to exceed swap + a configurable amount
>     (default is 50%) of physical RAM.  Depending on the amount you
>     use, in most situations this means a process will not be
>     killed while accessing pages but will receive errors on memory
>     allocation as appropriate.
>
>   Useful for applications that want to guarantee their memory
>     allocations will be available in the future without having to
>     initialize every page.

**Minimal experiment**

We can easily see the maximum allowed value with:

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *chars;
    size_t nbytes;

    /* Decide how many ints to allocate. */
    if (argc < 2) {
        nbytes = 2;
    } else {
        nbytes = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    }

    /* Allocate the bytes. */
    chars = mmap(
        NULL,
        nbytes,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
        -1,
        0
    );

    /* This can happen for example if we ask for too much memory. */
    if (chars == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Free the allocated memory. */
    munmap(chars, nbytes);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/eee6c825c3f64c4bf2bf0f437617a38937432549/userland/linux/mmap_anonymous.c).

Compile and run to allocate 1GiB and 1TiB:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out 0x40000000
./main.out 0x10000000000
```

We can then play around with the allocation value to see what the system allows.

I can't find a precise documentation for `0` (the default), but on my 32GiB RAM machine it does not allow the 1TiB allocation:

```
mmap: Cannot allocate memory
```

If I enable unlimited overcommit however:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

then the 1TiB allocation works fine.

Mode `2` is well documented, but I'm lazy to carry out precise calculations to verify it. But I will just point out that in practice we are allowed to allocate about:

```
overcommit_ratio / 100
```

of total RAM, and `overcommit_ratio` is `50` by default, so we can allocate about half of total RAM.

**VSZ vs RSS and the out-of-memory killer**

So far, we have just allocated virtual memory.

However, at some point of course, if you use enough of those pages, Linux will have to start killing some processes.

I have illustrated that in detail at: [What is RSS and VSZ in Linux memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management/57453334#57453334)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int Mb = 0;
    while (malloc(1<<20)) ++Mb;
    printf("Allocated %d Mb total\n", Mb);
}
```

Include stdlib and stdio for it.
This extract is taken from **deep c secrets**.

Comment: Darn... with a swap of like 100Gb you're going to wait quite a bit of time before you get your result. And better not have anything else running on your computer at that time!

Comment: On Linux, with the default virtual memory settings, your program will eventually be killed (with SIGKILL), rather than have `malloc` actually return NULL.

Comment: Like others have noted, this won't work as expected. (I guess someone needs to write Deep 'Deep C Secrets' Secrets). It will be killed rather than returning a null pointer. It also may well use swap or even disk-backed space depending on your system. And if your system uses memory overcommit together with lazy evaluation of allocated memory, it can easily appear to support tens of thousands of *gigabytes*, etc., before triggering the OS logic that says to kill the process for out-of-memory reasons.

Answer (score 7):

`malloc` does its own memory management, managing small memory blocks itself, but ultimately it uses the Win32 [Heap functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to allocate memory. You can think of `malloc` as a "memory reseller".

The windows memory subsystem comprises physical memory (RAM) and virtual memory (HD). When physical memory becomes scarce, some of the pages can be copied from physical memory to virtual memory on the hard drive. Windows does this transparently.

By default, Virtual Memory is enabled and will consume the available space on the HD. So, your test will continue running until it has either allocated the full amount of virtual memory for the process (2GB on 32-bit windows) or filled the hard disk.

Answer (score 4):

As per C90 standard guarantees that you can get at least one object 32 kBytes in size, and this may be static, dynamic, or automatic memory. C99 guarantees at least 64 kBytes. For any higher limit, refer your compiler's documentation.

Also, malloc's argument is a size_t and the range of that type is [0,SIZE_MAX], so the maximum you can *request* is SIZE_MAX, which value varies upon implementation and is defined in `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually know why that failed, but one thing to note is that `malloc(4)" may not actually give you 4 bytes, so this technique is not really an accurate way to find your maximum heap size.

I found this out from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650895/if-free-knows-the-length-of-my-array-why-cant-i-ask-for-it-in-my-own-code).

For instance, when you declare 4 bytes of memory, the space directly before your memory could contain the integer 4, as an indication to the kernel of how much memory you asked for.

Comment: indeed, malloc usually give a multiple of 16 bytes. There is two reasons. One is that standard says malloc should return a pointer compatible with any data alignment. Thus addresses separated by less than 16 bytes coulnd't be returned. The other reason is that freed blocks usually store some data used for internal memory management and a block too short - say 4 bytes - couldn't store it.

Comment: @kriss
[i]
freed blocks usually store some data used for internal memory management and a block too short - say 4 bytes - couldn't store it.[/i]

Can you mention what kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

**Does malloc allocate memory from HD also?**

Implementation of `malloc()` depends on `libc` implementation and operating system (OS). Typically `malloc()` doesn't always request RAM from the OS but returns a pointer to previously allocated memory block "owned" by `libc`.

In case of POSIX compatible systems, this `libc` controlled memory area is usually increased using syscall `brk()`. That doesn't allow releasing any memory between two still existing allocations which causes the process to look still using all the RAM after allocating areas A, B, C in sequence and releasing B. This is because areas A and C around the area B are still in use so the memory allocated from the OS cannot be returned.

Many modern `malloc()` implementations have some kind of heuristic where small allocations use the memory area reserved via `brk()` and "big" allocations use anonymous virtual memory blocks reserved via `mmap()` using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag. This allows immediately returning these big allocations when `free()` is later called. Typically the runtime performance of `mmap()` is slightly slower than using previously reserved memory which is the reason `malloc()` implements this heuristic.

Both `brk()` and `mmap()` allocate virtual memory from the OS. And virtual memory can be always backed up by swap which may be stored in any storage that the OS supports, including HDD.

In case you run Windows, the syscalls have different names but the underlying behavior is probably about the same.

**What was the reason for above behaviour?**

Since your example code never touched the memory, I'd guess you're seeing behavior where OS implements copy-on-write for virtual RAM and the memory is mapped to shared page with whole page filled with zeroes by default. Modern operating systems do this because many programs allocate more RAM than they actually need and using shared zero page by default for all memory allocations avoids needing to use real RAM for these allocations.

If you want to test how OS handles your loop and actually reserve true storage, you need to write something to the memory you allocated. For x86 compatible hardware you only need to write one byte per each 4096 byte segment because page size is 4096 and the hardware cannot implement copy-on-write behavior for smaller segments; once one byte is modified, the whole 4096 byte segment called page must be reserved for your process. I'm not aware of any modern CPU that would support smaller than 4096 byte pages. Modern Intel CPUs support 2 MB and 1 GB pages in addition to 4096 byte pages but the 1 GB pages are rarely used because the overhead of using 2 MB pages is small enough for any sensible RAM amounts. 1 GB pages might make sense if your system has hundreds of terabytes of RAM.

So basically your program only tested reserving virtual memory without ever using said virtual memory. Your OS probably has special optimization for this which avoids needing more than 4 KB of RAM to support this.

Unless your objective is to try to measure the overhead caused by your `malloc()` implementation, you should avoid trying to allocate memory block smaller than 16-32 bytes. For `mmap()` allocations the minimum possible overhead is 8 bytes per allocation on x86-64 hardware due the data needed to return the memory to the operating system so it really doesn't make sense for `malloc()` to use `mmap()` syscall for a single 4 byte allocation.

The overhead is needed to keep track of memory allocations because the memory is freed using `void free(void*)` so memory allocation routines must keep track of the allocated memory segment size somewhere. Many `malloc()` implementations also need additional metadata and if they need to keep track of any memory addresses, those need 8 bytes per address.

If you truly want to search for the limits of your system, you should probably do binary search for the limit where `malloc()` fails. In practice, you try to allocate ..., 1KB, 2KB, 4KB, 8KB, ..., 32 GB which then fails and you know that the real world limit is between 16 GB and 32 GB. You can then split this size in half and figure out the exact limit with additional testing. If you do this kind of search, it may be easier to always release any successful allocation and reserve the test block with a single malloc() call. That should also avoid accidentally accounting for `malloc()` overhead so much because you need only one allocation at any time at max.

Update: As pointed out by Peter Cordes in the comments, your `malloc()` implementation may be writing bookkeeping data about your allocations in the reserved RAM which causes real memory to be used and that can cause system to start swapping so heavily that you cannot recover it in any sensible timescale without shutting down the computer. In case you're running Linux and have enabled "Magic SysRq" keys, you could just press `Alt`+`SysRq`+`f` to kill the offending process taking all the RAM and system would run just fine again. It is possible to write `malloc()` implementation that doesn't usually touch the RAM allocated via `brk()` and I assumed you would be using one. (This kind of implementation would allocate memory in 2^n sized segments and all similarly sized segments are reserved in the same range of addresses. When `free()` is later called, the `malloc()` implementation knows the size of the allocation from the address and bookkeeping about free memory segments are kept in separate bitmap in single location.) In case of Linux, `malloc()` implementation touching the reserved pages for internal bookkeeping is called dirtying the memory, which prevents sharing memory pages because of copy-on-write handling.

**Why didn't loop break at any point of time?**

If your OS implements the special behavior described above and you're running 64-bit system, you're not going to run out of virtual memory in any sensible timescale so your loop seems infinite.

**Why wasn't there any allocation failure?**

You didn't actually use the memory so you're allocating virtual memory only. You're basically increasing the maximum pointer value allowed for your process but since you never access the memory, the OS never bothers the reserve any physical memory for your process.

In case you're running Linux and want the system to enforce virtual memory usage to match actually available memory, you have to write `2` to kernel setting `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and maybe adjust `overcommit_ratio`, too. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441364/20336 for details about memory overcommit on Linux. As far as I know, Windows implements overcommit, too, but I don't know how to adjust its behavior.

Comment: You discuss never touching the memory.  That would make sense with larger allocations of multiple pages each.  But the OP used `malloc(4)`.  There won't be untouched pages; they'll all be full of bookkeeping info (like the size of the allocation, typically stored in the bytes bytes before the pointer returned by malloc).  Also maybe gaps for alignment; `alignof(max_align_t)` is only 8 on Windows x64, but IIRC malloc there usually returns memory aligned by 16 like on x86-64 Linux where max_align_t is 16 bytes.

Comment: So what happened in the question is just swap thrashing as they allocate+dirty page after page, bringing the system to its knees and making the GUI unresponsive so they had a hard time killing this one.  It is useful to describe what happens when you allocate lots of untouched pages (eventually running out of virtual address space), but the one mistake in your answer is saying that's what the code in the question was doing.

Comment: Good point about `malloc()` internal bookkeeping potentially touching the memory and causing copy-on-write to create private pages! That would indeed cause trashing when system tries to push least-recently used pages to swap.

Comment: Interesting, I'd wondered if malloc/free implementations were possible using the address to figure out the size, without per-allocation bookkeeping.  Cool to hear that some actually do this, and yeah I see how that would work well for a few common sizes, especially small power-of-2 allocations.

Comment: I have never checked but my understanding is that GNU `libc` implements `malloc()` like I described to mostly avoid bookkeeping per allocation.

Comment: I've only looked much at larger allocations, especially above the mmap threshold.  Then it typically returns a pointer that's `p % 4096 == 16`, so I assume it must put bookkeeping info (like a size) before the pointer it's going to return, which is aligned by 16 to satisfy `alignof(max_align_t) == 16` in x86-64 SysV.  This is always misaligned for AVX (32-byte vectors), unfortunately.  I had assumed it would work the same way for small allocations, but maybe not.  From the symptoms the OP describes, their Windows malloc did work that way.

Comment: I tested with glibc 2.35 on x86-64 Arch Linux; it touches all the pages it allocates with `brk`, with 4-byte mallocs.  I replaced the OP's infinite loop with one up to 10M, still with 4 byte allocations, then put a sleep(100) after it so I could observe the RSS.  Compiling with `-O1` or lower so the unused malloc doesn't get optimized away, RSS is 306.1MiB, VIRT is 307.  So every page was touched, and it allocates about 32 bytes per 4-byte malloc. (306.1 MiB / 10e6 is 32.09).  Probably 16 for bookkeeping + alignment for that, and another 16 for the allocation + alignment padding for that.

Comment: Another test with malloc(16) had basically the same resident-set size, 305.9 MiB (amount of memory backed by physical RAM, i.e. how much is dirty if nothing's been swapped out).  That was expected.  More interesting is that `malloc(17)` also produces the same result, 32 bytes used per malloc(17) or malloc(24).  `malloc(25)` bumps up to 458.6 MiB used, so 48 bytes per allocation.  So bookkeeping overhead is 8 bytes, probably just a size.  Again, this is all glibc 2.35 on x86-64 Linux.

Comment: Great info! The actual implementation can be found here: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c – There's a lot of documentation in the comments and it seems to keep two `size_t` objects for every allocated segment. It contains interesting optimization that it keeps extra bookkeeping details in free memory segments (areas that are reserved from OS using `brk()` but not released). So it seems the current implementation doesn't implement the possible optimization I described above to avoid keeping track of size per allocation.

Answer (score 1):

I use the MemAvailable parameter in /proc/meminfo on Linux to make an initial estimate of the free RAM then use a binary chop to confirm.  My intention is to determine the largest physical RAM that I can claim using malloc but it's still a bit hacky and could potentially cause swapping, though in practice it seems to have been behaving fairly well, at least on the 64 bit Raspberry Pi 4 systems I'm using.  Have a look at https://github.com/gtoal/biggest-malloc and let me know if it works or doesn't for you and if not, which linux, what memory, and how did it fail? (post on github rather than here. Thanks.).

Answer (score -3):

when first time you allocate any size to *p, every next time you leave that memory to be unreferenced. That means

> at a time your program is allocating memory of 4 bytes only

. then how can you thing you have used entire RAM, that's why **SWAP device( temporary space on HDD)** is out of discussion. I know an memory management algorithm in which when no one program is referencing to memory block, that block is eligible to allocate for programs memory request. That's why you are just keeping busy to **RAM Driver** and that's why it can't give chance to service other programs. Also this a dangling reference problem.

Ans : You can at most allocate the memory of your RAM size. Because no program has access to swap device.

I hope your all questions has got satisfactory answers.

Comment: That's simply incorrect. I tried to run 8Gb allocations in a loop, it managed to run for 16382 allocations, thats 128Tb - I don't have that much RAM at least. In fact not even that much swap (see my comment to the accepted answer).

Comment: Because of compressed memory maybe?

Comment: "you leave that memory to be unreferenced" there is no reference counting in place here. The memory is not released despite not having anything point to it.

Comment: @JustinCB: No, because of overcommit and lazy allocation: not actually allocating physical pages to back those virtual pages until/unless they're touched.  And read-only access would just make a page copy-on-write mapped to a shared page of zeros.  (IDK if "unreferenced" here was intended as "untouched", or to describe a memory leak.)  Anyway, this answer isn't correct, untouched allocation is limited only by virtual address space (yeah, about 128 TiB is the low half of the canonical range on x86-64 with 48-bit virtual adds) as long as you allocate in large enough chunks, not physical RAM.