# How to write a simple "page fault generator"?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, kernel, microbenchmark

For my course project on Linux Kernel, I need to simulate a situation where there is a **lot of page swapping** due to low memory.

I want to write a program which needs a lot of physical memory, so that pages accessed by this program have to be swapped in and out multiple times.

Comment: use calloc. See these threads: http://superuser.com/questions/278855/a-linux-program-that-uses-memory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383059/malloc-memory-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of, so first of all *you really need to allocate a buffer larger than your RAM size*. I hope you run on a 64bit OS or you have PAE enabled. If have let's say 4GB of RAM, you need something like:

```
double* pBigArray = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 536870912); 
// You actually need more than that. This is just 4GB.
```

Now, just having an array, larger than your RAM size is not enough. **It matters how you access it**. If you just read elements consecutively, the hardware prefetchers in your CPU will bring some of the data your program will read, into the cache.

To generate many **page faults**, you need to read from an address that is not in the RAM.

To do that this is a simple method, by reading from the array randomly:

```
double lfBigChecksum = 0.0;
while (true)
{
   int iIndex = rand() % BUFFER_SIZE;
   lfBigChecksum += pBigArray[iIndex];
}
```

If you have an array of 8GB and 4GB of RAM, half of the reads will be page faults (and served from the swap space in the hard disk).

Comment: Good answer. Just curious, but why allocate "doubles" instead of single byte chars?  He could just as easily write `malloc(4294967296ULL);`

Comment: Well, because a cache line fits less doubles (only 8) than chars (64) and the chances of hitting same cache line are reduced. Other than that, there's no real reason.

Comment: Also, if he's running 32-bit OS, he'd wouldn't be able to allocate 4GB.  `malloc` would shrug and return NULL immediately.  He could malloc in a loop of say 100MB until malloc returns NULL. And if needed, he could have several instances of his program running to force page-swapping on 32-bit.

Comment: That's true. Hopefully he has 64bit or PAE enabled. If not, what you propose seems a good solution.

Comment: One thing in the above code to account for. `rand()` only returns a value between **0-0x7fffffff**.  I guess that implicitly works itself out if if he uses a double array instead of a char array like I was thinking.  But he could say this in the loop: `size_t iIndex = rand()|(((size_t)rand())<<8) % BUFFER_SIZE;`

Comment: @VAndrei How do you identify `iIndex` that cause page-fault from those that does not? Is there a time limit to be consider time caused by cpu-stall due to  page-fault ?

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin you could measure the transaction time with a high resolution counter. A page fault would have high latency. Do this for all transactions and then make a histogram to determine if there is an observable threshold.

Answer (score -3):

You can eat up a ton of memory just by dynamically allocating tons of space and not using it. IE in C++ you can do

```
int *foo = new int[10000000];
```

Which will just eat up 40MB (assuming your `int`s are 4 btyes) and do nothing with it. Do this a couple of times (you may need to spread it out over several processes) and you'll eat up your RAM fast.

Comment: [David Grinberg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1305516/david-grinberg) From my understanding, unless I use the allocated memory, physical memory wont be affected (only virtual memory is allocated). Is this not the case?

Comment: @Venkatesh you are "using" it. We're using dumb pointers in C++, its not smart enough to tell if you are _really_ using it. Simply by declaring it you are using the memory. You can try it out yourself - check your memory before, then run this, then check memory again while its running (make sure to put a `while(true)` at the end).

Comment: I am using C language. And I allocated dynamic memory using `int *foo = malloc(10000000);`. However my RSS is just 356 KB (as reported by `/proc/$pid/status`).