# C - How much memory can a program allocate for itself - and how is it determined?

Tags: c, memory

Is there a limit to the amount of memory that can be allocated from a program? By that I mean, is there any protection from a program, for example, that allocates memory in an infinite loop?

When would the call to `malloc()` return a NULL pointer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [maximum memory which malloc can allocate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate)

Comment: It will depend on your operating system.

Comment: This discussion becomes even more complicated when you consider demand-paging operating systems; so long as you don't write anything to the newly allocated memory it is *not* fully allocated. This means you can allocate 2 GiB of memory on systems with only 32 MiB of RAM and `malloc (...)` will return immediately... the second you read/write that memory for the first time the kernel finally does the true allocation. That's why failure of `malloc (...)` is more indicative of running out of address space than running out of actual storage. Needless to say real-time OS's don't use demand-paging :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a limit.  What that limit is depends on many factors, including (but not limited to):

- The instruction set of the program (32-bit binaries have a smaller address space than 64-bit binaries, for example).
- How much memory the system has free.  ("Memory" here includes virtual memory.)
- Any artificial restrictions set by the system administrator or a privileged process (see, for example, [`setrlimit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) and the (obsolete) [`ulimit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html) function).

When memory cannot be allocated, `malloc()` will return `NULL`.  If the system is completely out of memory, your process may be terminated forcefully.

Comment: +1 for mentioning setrlimit().  See also ulimit (the bane of my existence for 4 years working with AIX, and another 2 years under Debian Linux -- both of which ship with artificially low defaults).

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Forgot about ulimit, thanks for pointing that out.  Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Allocation_size_limits),

> The largest possible memory block `malloc` can allocate depends on the
>   host system, particularly the size of physical memory and the
>   operating system implementation. Theoretically, the largest number
>   should be the maximum value that can be held in a `size_t` type, which
>   is an implementation-dependent unsigned integer representing the size
>   of an area of memory. The maximum value is 2<sup>`CHAR_BIT × sizeof(size_t)`</sup>
>   `− 1`, or the constant `SIZE_MAX` in the C99 standard.

Comment: This is useful information, but is about the largest *single* allocation request that `malloc()` can satisfy.  The question seems to be about a limit on the sum total of many allocations.

Comment: @Jacob what is `CHAR_BIT` ? Clion saying it is undeclared identifier ? or do you mean  `sizeof(char)` ?

Comment: @cdhowie I think that's also gives memory allocated to program only, isn't it ? That's what asked in Question.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the operating system and the standard library.

On Linux,

- When you run out of address space, `malloc()` will return `NULL`.
- When you run out of both physical memory and swap space, the OOM killer will run and kill a process to free memory.

Comment: Doesn't GNU malloc (which is typically used on linux) also have a max limit on single invocations, even if there is enough address space?

Comment: It should be easy enough to find, if you dig through glibc.

Comment: Did a test on my system (linux 5.4.72-gentoo, glibc-2.32, x86_64). `malloc` seems to have an upper limit of  8012111176 bytes, or 0x1dd8f1d48 in hex.

Comment: @HAL9000: Is that a glibc limit or an mmap limit?

Comment: Don't know, I just tried to see if there was an upper limit for `malloc` using bisection.

Comment: If you find what's causing it, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Digging through glibc is not easy, but i tried the same tests with `mmap`. It gave me an upper limit of 8012107776 bytes,  or 0x1dd8f1000 in hex. This is a little bit more than my mem+swap. Not sure if that is related.

Answer (score 0):

I am tackling this issue in Reverse.
See `pointer` stores addresses of memory blocks. If we able to find maximum address it can store then we can find memory allocated to our program.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    void *p;
    printf("%zu",sizeof(p));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
8
```

**Understanding:**

```
pointer size is 8 bytes.
8 bytes -> 64 bits
Max address it can store/ last memory block address: 2^64-1
Memory block addresses: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 2^64-1
Memory allocated to program: 2^64 byte
```

Comment: You're referring more to the _addressable space_ of a 64 bit pointer, which is not quite answering the original question here. But otherwise you are correct in that a 64bit pointer would contain the value of `2^64 - 1` if you were on a system that could satisfy a 64GB memory request. Though there is a host of problems with that scenario on a modern OS, the least being that 64GB of memory is a tremendously large value

Comment: @sherrellbc see when we writing Code in `C++` we are just writing down as text when we compile then memory allocate for it's object code. So that's memory you are talking about right ? if we increased variables in memory while writing code then memory allocated to object code also increase. Then we are checking upper limit to that as pointer size is `8` bytes it can point upto `2^64-1` spaces means that's max amount of memory but that's theoretical I know normally we have RAM's around `16 GB` means `2^34-1` max address. This is what I think if I am wrong then please correct me.