# Process memory in task manager shows less than i am allocating

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

I have written a small program just to check if my program can acquire entire RAM of my PC. i am trying to allocate 4 GB. When i check with task manager it shows around 2 GB. i believe OS has some kind of memory management mechanism. If someone can provide me what is really happening it will be helpful for me.
[i am not taking care of memory leak as this is a test code]

```
int main()
{

    char* p;

    p = (char*)malloc((1024 * 1024 * 1024));
    p = (char*)malloc((1024 * 1024 * 1024));
    p = (char*)malloc((1024 * 1024 * 1024));
    p = (char*)malloc((1024 * 1024 * 1024));

    while (1){}

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance,

Sagar

Comment: It's a pretty deep and philosophical question what it means to "allocate memory". Have a thought. What should it mean? What could it mean? How would an OS deal with requests to allocate memory?

Comment: Is it a 32- or 64-bit application? Have you checked the result (value of `p`) after each allocation?

Comment: If you are using Windows 32, Windows allows only 2GB for user programs.

Comment: Thanks, It is 32 bit. I will try with 64bit

Comment: Even then you won't be able to "acquire entire RAM of my PC".

Comment: possible duplicate of [maximum memory which malloc can allocate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate)