# Malloc fails to allocate more than 4gb on 64bit machine

Tags: malloc

malloc returns a null pointer whenever I'm trying to allocate more than 4gb. sizeof(void*) is 8 and the machine has 256gb of physical memory of which most is unused so finding a contiguous block should be no problem. What could be the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Show your actual malloc call. Possibly the value being passed in isn't what you expect (e.g. integer overflow).

Comment: Exactly what library for `malloc` do you use? It could be that it is misconfigured, simply recompilation of an implementation adapted for 32-bit systems or even done by a lazy programmer that didn't want to bother with larger blocks.

Comment: Also have you actually tried to confirm that the limit is actually 4Gb? Here I manage to allocate 14Gb, but not 15Gb fx.

Comment: Also what is the platform you use? Operation system, compiler ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to a limitation in the `malloc` function. Maybe you'll find your answer in [This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate).

If you want an example of an obvious limitation, it will not give you more than the size of your RAM in terms of space.

Comment: The answer in the linked question shows that it may very well give more than the size of your RAM.

Comment: Well, the second answer does agree with my idea though, so i'm not even sure anymore !

Comment: I tried and managed to allocate 14Gb blocks in a loop, ran for 9361 iterations (thats 131054Gb), I have only 8Gb of RAM (AFAIK).