# How to use malloc() allocates memory more than RAM in redhat?

Tags: c, linux, memory

System information: Linux version 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-031.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Nov 23 12:55:32 EST 2015

RAM 48 GB

Problem: I want to malloc() 100 GB memory. But it fail to allocate on redhat system.

I find that 100GB can be allocated in macOS with 8 GB RAM (clang compile). I am very confuse about that.

Maybe lazy allocation described in this link? [Why malloc() doesn't stop on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164136/why-malloc-doesnt-stop-on-os-x?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But why linux system can not? I try ubuntu and redhat, both fail to to that.

---

**Result**:
After investigation, I find that the following two steps will let malloc() unlimited:

1. echo "1" > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
2. ulimit -v unlimited

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum memory which malloc can allocate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate)

Comment: Out of curiousity, why on earth would you ever need to allocate 100GB RAM?

Comment: @VolAnd Yes. similar problem. But I can't find an answer in that problem.

Comment: @Lundin You can think that this is my test. Actually, another guy write this in his code. I also very curiosity, and I want to understand the principle of mac OS can do that.

Comment: "I find that 100GB can be allocated in macOS with 8 GB RAM". That's an illusion. Read about memory overcommitment.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. The system is out of physical RAM or swap space.
2. In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit.

Possible solutions:

1. Reduce memory load on the system.
2. Increase physical memory or swap space.
3. Check if swap backing store is full.

I think these point can help you to understand malloc failure issue.

Input validation. For example, you've asked for many gigabytes of memory in a single allocation. The exact limit (if any) differs by malloc implementation; POSIX says nothing about a maximum value, short of its type being a size_t.

Allocation failures. With a data segment-based malloc, this means brk failed. This occurs when the new data segment is invalid, the system is low on memory, or the process has exceeded its maximum data segment size (as specified by RLIMIT_DATA). With a mapping-based malloc, this means mmap failed. This occurs when the process is out of virtual memory (specified by RLIMIT_AS), has exceeded its limit on mappings, or has requested too large a mapping. Note most modern Unix systems use a combination of brk and mmap to implement malloc, choosing between the two based on the size of the requested allocation.

Comment: This is a fact that the memory what I want to allocated more than RAM (100GB > 48GB). But the mac OS only 8GB RAM also can malloc(100GB). Why?

Comment: The redhat system is 64bit release. Maybe not in 32 bit mode? Increasing physical memory is out of my intention. Swap size is 4GB. I will check the third suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked swap space of Mac OS. Actually I faced this issue in java apps. At that time my machine was over loaded by processes and swap space was very less.

Comment: @Yuanshengliu MacOS is a 64 bits system and has dynamic virtual memory, and it lets you allocate huge chunks of memory (its lazy allocation greatly helps in that case). Linux (depending on the version) has different limitations.

Comment: Actually I am not aware about Mac OS. So can not say more on it.