# In C, as free() knows an array size, why isn't there a function that gets the array size?

Tags: c, arrays, size, free, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If free() knows the length of my array, why can’t I ask for it in my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650895/if-free-knows-the-length-of-my-array-why-cant-i-ask-for-it-in-my-own-code)

Searching around (including here at stackoverflow), I got that malloc() allocates an array and also creates a header to control the array info.

In this header, there's also the array size. free() use such information to know how to deallocate that array.

So, if the array size info is "there" (somewhere in the memory), why there isn't a function that returns an array size, looking for this at the array header? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Good question. I bet there is a way to get the size but it's platform dependent. I recall the win32 API having something for getting the size of an allocated block..